# Typescript definition file for module constructor?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

I am trying to write a `.d.ts` file for an [`npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ago) package, where it is typically used like:

```
var ago = require("ago")
ago(344) // 344 milliseconds ago, e.g. 1376505400233
```

I want to be able to use ES6 style imports with this. How can I define a module such that it can be imported, e.g. :

```
declare module "ago" {}
```

but then so it also behaves as a function as shown above?